# How to create or get a new StoreKey.pfx for UWP application

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-store-apps, uwp, pfx

when I first published my app the certificate was created automatically Visual Studio. I keep my project in git, and the file is there added to the list .gitignore. I cloned your repository on another computer and are going to release the app update in the store, but I have no certificate. How can I get it again?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `StoreKey.pfx` file will be automatically generated when you'll be creating the app package for the Store.

Or you can get it simply by associating your app with the Store using `Project > Store > Associate app with the Store...`

Comment: yes, its true! but I did not happen, and I understood why. It turns out the studio does not check the availability of the certificate in the file system and looks for the presence of references to the project. Only after I removed all mention of the .csproj then he recreated himself upon binding to the store!

Comment: Yes, more detail info, please refer to [Packaging UWP apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps).

Comment: More specifically, you have to delete the `PackageCertificateThumbprint` and `PackageCertificateKeyFile` elements in the csproj file. Then associate the app with Store again and it will generate a new pfx.

Comment: did that and no store pfx showed up... in any folders. very annoying.

Comment: Yeah it seems like this no longer generates the certificate... how are we supposed to get the Store certificate for building with Azure DevOps?

Comment: Anyone able to figure this out?

Comment: Outdated answer since 2020... https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/associate-app-with-the-store-doesnt-create-app-sto/702190

Comment: Check the answer by Timur Sadykov which reflects new Microsoft practice towards relying on temp PFX files during development and only generating the actual publication key when the app is actually published in the Microsoft Store.

Comment: Check the comment by Edgar directing one delete `PackageCertificateThumbprint` and `PackageCerticateKeyFile` and associating your app with its entry in the Microsoft Store.  At this point, without other errors, you should be able to compile your app and debug its Store API calls.

Comment: So if I needed a StoreKey pfx file, for something like Azure Devops pipeline, how do I get that?

Answer (score 1):

Generation of the StoreKey.pfx is now disabled.

MS decided to generate a temp cert during the build and then discard it. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/associate-app-with-the-store-doesnt-create-app-sto/702190

So you need to associate the app with the Store on every dev machine and for everything else - sign packages separately using this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/packaging-uwp-apps